# Why can't TypeScript do "type subtraction" with intersections (&)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Okay so I have two versions of my models, the "regular" model, and a "new" version of that model. "New" objects are objects that exist locally in my app's form before they've been committed to my API's datastore, and therefore do not have fields that are generated by my API, e.g. id, audit metadata like created/updated at/by, etc...

At various points in my app I want to know whether the object I have is "new" or fully-formed, so I want to make a type guard `isNew()`. I'd like the type guard to handle every model in my app, so I'd like to be generic.

```
function <T>isNew(obj: T & {id: number} | T): obj is T {
  return !('id' in obj);
}
```

This does not work :) I thought I was clever by defining the argument's type as `T & {id: number}`, thinking that it would imply `T` is whatever `obj` is except the id field, since `T` is anything plus an id field.

So in use this is what actually happens:

```
function upsert(model: Model | New<Model>) {
  const method = isNew(model) ? 'POST' : 'PUT'; 
  //             ^ isNew(obj: (Model | New<Model>) & { id: number} | (Model | New<Model>)): obj is Model | New<Model>
  //             this didn't change the type of model at all!
  ...
}
```

So I guess not only am I wanting "type subtraction" from the `&` operator, but I also want it to be able to dissect the union and extract the subtracted types from constituents where assignable.

This is all really complicated and I ended up just not doing anything like this because I don't really *need* that level of type information for my app to work. I can just say `const method = 'id' in model ? 'PUT' : 'POST'` and that works fine. Just kind of a pain to type that whole thing out everywhere whenever I do want that type information.

Besides, I'm mostly just curious about why TypeScript doesn't or can't work the way I thought it would when I thought I was being clever with `T & {id: number}`

Comment: `T` will always be inferred as the widest possible (most general) type where the operations on it still result in the same thing.